# Is there any management free wordpress hosting/website builder?

Tags: wordpress

There are plenty of providers offering "managed" Wordpress – but usually this just means that they install Wordpress for you, and you have to deal with the rest, technical maintenance etc.

https://wordpress.com seems like they offer this

I also found https://10web.io/ – but they write that from time to time you need to login to the ftp and delete the .maintenance file, exactly the kind of stuff I want to get rid off.

It's basically impossible to know from the website's description if it is really hassle-free, without trying it out. Did you make any stellar experiences with any service?

Comment: Hosting a website, no matter the platform, means maintaining it from time to time, specially when using the bug-ridden Wordpress. If you don't want to do it, hire someone to do it for you.

Comment: @Alejandro yikes, that's just rude ("bug-ridden"). Depending on how you look at it, that's "true" for loads of web applications. Personally avoiding a writable web root has been _the_ single biggest security-improvement for me in WordPress instances. And there we have it again: trading security for convenience (or the other way around).

Comment: @DreamFlasher: you're not really looking for a software recommendation, are you? Hi and welcome to SoftwareRecs.SE, btw.

Comment: Please note this site is about recommending *software,* not services – so this seems off-topic. For details, you might refer to our Meta post on [Are hosting recommendation requests on-topic?](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/675/185)

Comment: Seems like there is no place on stackexchange where this is not off-topic. It's unfortunate, I still believe this is a relevant question (and this category of question). And I disagree with @Alejandro, wix for example is maintenance-free as far as I can see it, and there are definitely big differences between services.